# how to build uWSGI with SSL support to use the websocket handshake API function?

Tags: python, nginx, websocket, uwsgi

**What I have:** 
ubuntu 14.4
uwsgi running with flask (python) with nginx as reverse proxy.

**What I want:**
running this example of WebSockets:
https://github.com/zeekay/flask-uwsgi-websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/echo.py

When I'm running this application with chromepy on port 5000, it is working fine but when I try to run without chromepy I get an error

**The error:**

```
Thu Jun 12 12:58:24 2014 - you need to build uWSGI with SSL support to use the websocket handshake api function !!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lab_alglab/rep/car/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/lab_alglab/rep/car/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_uwsgi_websocket/websocket.py", line 54, in __call__
    uwsgi.websocket_handshake(environ['HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY'], environ.get('HTTP_ORIGIN', ''))
IOError: unable to complete websocket handshake
```

Comment: When i'm running directly from uWSGI with
$ uwsgi --master --http :8080 --http-websockets --wsgi echo:app
it is working fine.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. I have tried reconfiguring uwsgi both within and outside my virtualenv with "pip install uwsgi -I", which seems to indicate that SSL is enabled. There might however be some conflict with the native uwsgi install? Is it somehow possible to test whether SSL is enabled?

Answer (score 18):

I had to install OpenSSL via brew. Then run this command.

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE=ssl=true pip install uwsgi -Iv
```

Comment: This works for me (reinstalling with the `-I` and `--no-cache-dir` options): `CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE=ssl=true pip install uwsgi -I --no-cache-dir`

Comment: On OS X Sierra for me worked with this command: `CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE=ssl=true pip install uwsgi -Iv --no-use-wheel`; Note the `--no-use-wheel`

Comment: the flags to force it to build via source seem to keep changing; it's `CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE=ssl=true pip install uwsgi --no-binary :all:` in pip 18

Comment: Adding Pip's `--no-cache-dir` could avoid some confusion as well.

Comment: @Rockallite
tanx a lot

Answer (score 7):

As one of the poster's below mentioned, you'll need the openssl headers, and if they're in a non-traditional place (for example on Mac OS-X) you have to let uWSGI know.

On Debian/Ubuntu install them with "apt-get install libssl-dev".  They'll go in /usr/include/" which is part of UWSGI's automatic path.  You should be done.

Mac OS-X El Capitan (10.11) removed the openssl headers.  You can check common places with this command--they may have been installed by a package manager like brew or macports.

```
find /usr/local/include /usr/include /opt/local/include /usr/local/ssl/include -name openssl -type d 2> /dev/null
```

If that command returns nothing, you'll need to install the headers.  You can install them with MacPorts (port install openssl) which will put them in /opt/local/include with a link in /usr/local/include.  You can also install them directly, by downloading and untarballing openssl, running "./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc", then "make", and finally "sudo make install".

Xcode's build utilities package a whole pre-defined build environment. With XCode projects that means developers have a common base to work from, and anything not in the base must be in XCode project.  Building open source projects outside the base, gets a bit messy because dependencies like openssl live outside the base directories.  You can give uwsgi's build chain ONE include directory to use.  It doesn't support the PATH style : separator.

In most install cases, the following should work on OpenSSL.

```
UWSGI_INCLUDES=/usr/local/include/ pip install uwsgi
```

Answer (score 3):

just install openssl development headers (libssl-dev) and rebuild uwsgi (its build system will automatically detect ssl availability)

Comment: ################# uWSGI configuration #################
    
    pcre = False
    kernel = Linux
    malloc = libc
    execinfo = False
    ifaddrs = True
    ssl = True
    zlib = True
    locking = pthread_mutex
    plugin_dir = .
    timer = timerfd
    yaml = embedded
    json = False
    filemonitor = inotify
    routing = False
    debug = False
    capabilities = False
    xml = libxml2
    event = epoll
    
    ############## end of uWSGI configuration #############

Comment: In the case you're using docker images based on `alpine`, install `openssl-dev` package.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my version of this issue by installing uwsgi through pip (outside venv), and changing the init script (Ubuntu) /etc/init.d/uwsgi to run the newly installed 2.x branch (instead of 1.9).

Pip installed to /user/local/bin, so I changed the line daemon to: DAEMON="/usr/local/bin/uwsgi"

Comment: Installing uwsgi **outside venv was the key to me!

Answer (score 1):

Solution for `Ubuntu 20.04` and `python 3.8.10` and `pip` installed via `apt` as system packages:

```sh
# switch to root because system packages can't be changed without root privileges
# This is not necessary for user based environment like virtualenv or pyenv
sudo su -

# Uninstall previous version of `uwsgi` if exists
pip uninstall uwsgi

# Install libraries for SSL support
apt-get install libssl-dev

## Manually build uwsgi with SSL support
# set necessary lib paths
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/openssl"
# aarch64-linux-gnu folder used for ARM architecture and may be different for your env
# use [apt-file list libssl-dev] to check lib folders (apt-file should be additionally installed)
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu"
# activate SSL support
export UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE=ssl=true
# build uwsgi using pip (--no-use-wheel depricated so used --no-binary instead)
# this command will install 2.0.20 version. Version may be changed or removed. It is not mandatory
pip install -I --no-binary=:all: --no-cache-dir uwsgi==2.0.20

# Check SSL support
uwsgi --help | grep https
```

Expected output:

```
    --https-socket                          bind to the specified UNIX/TCP socket using HTTPS protocol
    --https-socket-modifier1                force the specified modifier1 when using HTTPS protocol
    --https-socket-modifier2                force the specified modifier2 when using HTTPS protocol
    --https                                 add an https router/server on the specified address with specified certificate and key
    --https2                                add an https/spdy router/server using keyval options
    --https-export-cert                     export uwsgi variable HTTPS_CC containing the raw client certificate
    --https-session-context                 set the session id context to the specified value
    --http-to-https                         add an http router/server on the specified address and redirect all of the requests to https
```

<sub>Based on other answers and comments in this thread. Thank you guys</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the location of the development headers with `LDFLAGS`. As an aside, this can happen on OS X as well due to El Capitan no longer shipping headers.

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" pip install uwsgi --no-use-wheel
```