# uwsgi: unrecognized option '--https'

Tags: django, https, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi 2.0.8 on AWS. I followed the instructions on http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/HTTPS.html to start my web app.

```
uwsgi --master --https 0.0.0.0:8443,foobar.crt,foobar.key
```

However, it reports this error: `uwsgi: unrecognized option '--https'`.

Anyone helps?

PS: I also installed uwsgi 2.0.8 on my own MBP, it works well with `--https`.

Comment: I find the solution. Just because I installed `uwsgi` without ssl support. I installed `libssl-dev` and rebuilt `uwsgi` again, it works finally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to build uWSGI with SSL support to use the websocket handshake API function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183053/how-to-build-uwsgi-with-ssl-support-to-use-the-websocket-handshake-api-function)

Answer (score 8):

Below are how I solved the same issue:

1. pip uninstall uwsgi
2. sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
3. (Assume I am at /mnt/server) git clone https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi.git
4. cd uwsgi
5. python uwsgiconfig.py --build
6. (Let us test) sudo /mnt/server/uwsgi/uwsgi --master --https 0.0.0.0:443,foobar.crt,foobar.key,HIGH,ca.crt --chdir /mnt/server/mysite --module mysite.wsgi

Answer (score 1):

Try installing uwsgi with below mentioned command on mac:

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE=ssl=true pip install uwsgi -Iv
```

And if you are trying on Centos, then make sure openssl and openssl-devel package is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I was on a limited RedHat 7.7 instance and `libssl-dev` was unavailable to me, I was able to use `openssl-devel` instead.

Note: I also needed to update [`iptables`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) to open port 8443 since my instance was pretty locked down

`uwsgi --master --https 0.0.0.0:8443,foobar.crt,foobar.key` then works as expected.