# Dockerfile for building uWSGI with SSL support

Tags: docker, ssl, uwsgi

I am building a Docker container with uWSGI with the following `Dockerfile` instructions (relevant excerpt):

```
FROM debian:stretch
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
  gcc python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools
RUN pip3 install wheel
RUN pip3 install uwsgi
```

Later on, when invoking the WebSocket I encounter this error message:

> you need to build uWSGI with SSL support to use the websocket
>   handshake api function

How I can build uWSGI with SSL support in the context of a Debian-based Docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following now works for me:

```
FROM debian:stretch
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
  gcc libssl-dev python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools
RUN pip3 install wheel
RUN CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" \
  UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE=ssl=true pip3 install uwsgi -Iv
```

I was helped by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38842664) related answer. I also had to overcome an irritation that stemmed from having installed OpenSSH only in a later part of the `Dockerfile`: this made it seem as if SSH libraries were available to the uWSGI compilation step when in reality they were not yet present during that step. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47860810) answer was useful for testing the resulting web socket from a command line.